# Gradle not compiling dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I'm trying to execute the "Hello World" example from Android Studio but I get this error

- Android Studio: 1.5.1
- Gradle: 2.12
- Apache Ant: 1.10.3
  I have no admin privileges and I'm under a proxy (I got the configuration IP, user/pass correctly added in the settings section).

Here are some screenshots.
Thanks in advance for your help!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old configuration, old Android studio. Update to the newest official one:

**Android Studio: 3.1.2, Gradle: 3.1.2**

Also edit the file gradle-wrapper.properties and change the url to this:

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip**

And delete all directory versions of gradle in the directory .gradle\, like .gradle\4.1, .gradle\2.12, and so on.

After that, try to sync your project again and clean+rebuild the whole project.